# C++ [recursion] find longest sequence of values greater than 0

Tags: c++, recursion

i am having trouble making a solution that uses recursion to find the longest sequence of values in an array that are > 0.
for example if this array is passed into the function:

```
const int LongestVal[13] =
{ 11, -8, 5, 3, 2, -5, 12, 8, 3, 6, -1, -2,  };
```

should return 4. (12, 8, 3, 6)

I have a pretty good grasp on recursion but so far have been unsuccessful in finding a way to do this. And havent found any other posts like this.
I have also been able to write a function (not using recursion) that performs the task.

```
int longest(const int a[],int size) {
    int count = 0; //counter for counting # > 0
    int max_count = 0; //return value of max count
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (a[i] > 0) {
            count++; //increment for every + number in a row
            if (count > max_count)
                max_count = count; //set if current count streak is highest
        }
        else
            count = 0; //reset count on # <= 0
    }
    return max_count; 
}
```

Comment: Is recursion a requirement? I can see a very simple and efficient way of solving this via a simple loop, but how to add recursion there... that will take some thought.

Comment: Post your best attempt at solving this with recursion; let us work on that.

Comment: @Vilx- Iterative solution is already in the question.

Comment: I guess im confused on where to start as in where would the base case be?

Comment: The base case is a[i] <= 0; at that point, you return a length of 0, and let the parent calls add +1 to the length they see from the immediate child.  Is that enough to push you to the solution?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius - Oh, right, should read that stuff. ^^)

Comment: thanks, thats a good place to start from. Will post back if I cannot figure it out further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the recursive function edited from your iterative one-

```
int longest(const int a[],int size,int count,int max_count) {

    //base case
    if(size<0)
      return max_count;

    if (a[size] > 0) {
        count++; //increment for every + number in a row
        if (count > max_count)
            max_count = count; //set if current count streak is highest
    }
    else
        count = 0; //reset count on # <= 0

    size--;  //array will be traversed from end to start
    max_count=longest(a,size,count,max_count);

    return max_count; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use recursive. A simple solution is:

```
int longest(const int a[], int start, int end) {
    int longest = 0;
    int currentLength = 0;
    for (int i = start; i <= end; ++i)
    {
        int value = i < end ? a[i] : -1;
        if (value <= 0)
        {
            longest = currentLength > longest ? currentLength : longest;
            currentLength = 0;
        }
        else
            currentLength++;
    }
    return longest;
}
```

If you really want to play with recursive, just call this function size times by iterating start from 0 to size-1 and keep end = size, which will be the same as just call start = 0 and end = size;